# Why can't I make a connection to a remote mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, jdbc

I was given some credentials, but I appear to be missing something here, as the script errors out when trying to make a connection.

```
import mysql.connector

def test_sql_query():
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host='hostname', database='db', user='dbuser,' password='dbpass', port='000')
    cur = db.cursor()
    if db.is_connected():
        print('Connected to MySQL database')
    try:
        sql_command = "select * from test where test like '%FileUploadAgent%' and status='00' order by test desc;"
        cur.execute(sql_command)
        db.commit()
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print "   ", row[1][1]
    except:
        print "did not work"
    db.close()
```

I was provided with the following credentials: host, user, passwd, driver, jdbc.url, port

In my sql script there is nowhere that I am using driver or jdbc.url.  What are these two things and are they required to make a database connection.  Is this why I am unable to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if the remote database is allowed to connect remotely.

[How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

this line is missing comma:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect("host='hostname' database='db' user='dbuser' password='dbpass' port='000'")
```

replace to

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(host='hostname', user='dbuser', passwd='dbpass', db='db')
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo, i corrected the OP, i still can't establish the db connection though.

Comment: look the comma in this line: mysql.connector.connect(host='hostname', database='db', user='dbuser,' password='dbpass', port='000') - in dbuser is wrong place